# SSIS Load data from Excel .xlsx without installing 32 bit driver

Tags: ssis-2012

I need to load data from excel with .xlsx extension to Netezza table. I get following error.
The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode.

Is there any way to use excel with .xlsx extension without installing 32- bit driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the project property **Run64BitRuntime** to **True**.

[image]

More information can be found in Microsoft's article - [64 bit Considerations for Integration Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141766(v=sql.105).aspx).

> When you run a package in 64-bit mode, you might not be able to
>   connect to as many data sources as you can when you run a package in
>   32-bit mode. Some .NET Framework Data Providers and native OLE DB
>   providers might not be available in 64-bit versions. For example, the
>   Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet, which connects to Access databases
>   and Excel spreadsheets, is not available in a 64-bit version. Also,
>   the SQL Server Compact Provider, which connects to SQL Server Compact
>   data sources, is not available in a 64-bit version.
>
> > The ACE
> >     Provider and its Excel 2010 driver (64-bit, 32-bit) can be used with
> >     Integration Services under certain circumstances. For more information
> >     and to download the provider, see [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255).
>
> The 32-bit SSIS Designer displays only 32-bit
>   providers that are installed on the local computer. To configure a
>   connection manager to use a specific 64-bit provider, you must install
>   the 32-bit version of the provider on the development computer for use
>   at design time. Even though the 32-bit version of the provider is
>   installed, you can still run the package in 64-bit mode, both in the
>   development environment and after deployment. The 32-bit and 64-bit
>   versions of a provider have the same ID. Therefore, the SSIS runtime
>   will select the appropriate version of the provider to use. For
>   example, you run the package in the development environment on a
>   64-bit computer. By default, the package uses the 64-bit version of
>   the provider because the default value of the **Run64BitRuntime** project
>   property is **True**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this. I was curious to know if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: It sounds like you have neither the 32-bit or 64-bit driver installed?   In order to read data from xlsx files, yes you will need a driver.  I have linked to the driver download in my answer.